# How to enable `at` command in Ubuntu Linux & Communication with Modem

Tags: ubuntu, sms, at-command, modem, sms-gateway

I want to create my own private SMS gateway and software in my computer. I am using Ubuntu 14.04. Can any one tell me the step by step processes.

1. How can I enable the `AT` command?
2. How can I send command to modem and get reply from modem?

I do not want to use third party software. If I can send the `AT` command then I will create my own SMS sending software.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is rather broad...

Here are a few sources to start reading for *modems* with Ubuntu:

- *[DialupModemHowto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DialupModemHowto)*
- *[Modem-HOWTO](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Modem-HOWTO.html)*
- *[12.3. Configure modem with AT commands](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Remote-Serial-Console-HOWTO/modem-hayes.html)* (Remote Serial Console HOWTO)

Setting up an SMS gateway is a more specialized topic, and probably depends heavily upon your configuration.  For example:

- [GSM modem based wireless links vs IP SMS connections to the mobile network](http://www.ozekisms.com/index.php?owpn=647)
- [Diafaan SMS Server](http://www.diafaan.com/diafaan-sms-server/)
- [GSM Modems](http://www.nowsms.com/doc/configuring-smsc-connections/gsm-modems)